# Translation of a Line in a Poem

Tags: translation, german-to-english

My great-grandfather had written a book of Poems in German. We've been able to translate most of them,  but having trouble with an English translation for this one, especially the last line of the first stanza. Can anyone help with this one?  If it helps, he (the author) was born in the 1880's in Switzerland. I included the entire poem for context and our attempt at translation. None of us are German speakers, so any help is appreciated!

> **Trinkspruch**
> Unser Leben gleicht der Reise eines Wandrers in der Nacht.
> Wer hat nicht in trüber Stunde diese Worte schon bedacht?
> Auch in heitern Sonnentagen tät es manchem Menschen gut,
> **Etwa an das Lied zu denken, wenn zu heiß das leichte Blut,**
>
> Freudenbecher sind zwar nötig, wenn man nicht verkümmern will.
> Doch es ruft uns zu die Klugheit: Nicht zu oft und nicht zuviel!
> Wer sein Leben weiß zu regeln auch in froher Sommerszeit,
> Ist viel besser vorbereitet für des Winters Dunkelheit.

Our attempted translation:

> **Toast**
> Our life is like the journey of a wanderer at night
> Who has not already considered these words in a dark hour?
> Even on sunny days it would do some people good
> **To think of the song, if the light blood is too hot.**
>
> Friends are necessary,  if you don't want to wither.
> But it calls us to be wise: not too often and not too much!
> Who knows how to manage his life even in the happy summer time,
> Is much better prepared for the winter’s darkness

Thanks.

Sue

[image]

Comment: Freudenbecher sind zwar nötig, wenn man nicht verkümmern will. = beakers of joy are essential if you don't want to wither

Comment: Doch es ruft uns zu die Klugheit =but wisdom calls out to us

Comment: Are you sure it is "Lied" and not "Leid"? The latter would fit the context better.

Comment: @Roland  I just added an image to the original post.  "Lied" is what was in the booklet I have.  I have no idea if that is a typo. I found it in my grandfather's papers after he passed away. No one in the family knew of the poem collection, so I have no idea if it was a typo in the booklet itself.

Comment: It seems to be a typo, as "Leid" makes much more sense in the context than"Lied".

Comment: The photograph clearly reads "Lied".

Comment: @RichardNeumann Sure. I think, it is a typo in the print. :)

Answer (score 5):

The other answers who believe `Lied` is in fact a misspelling of `Leid` are missing an important fact: The first line of the poem (`Unser Leben gleicht der Reise...`) is a direct quote from the *[Beresinalied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beresinalied)*, a German song very well known in Switzerland. So the poet was indeed referring to this rather gloomy song, and your translation is a good representation of the original meaning.

The Wikipedia article has a good discussion of the cultural significance of the *Beresinalied* in Switzerland; to summarize, it represents something like an Alamo / Masada moment of Swiss history.

Comment: I like this interpretation. I don't know why everybody jumped the gun calling it a typo, just because they "felt" it would fit better with another word. Given the context of the poem provided by the OP, your interpretation makes perfect sense unlike the wild assumptions of others.

Answer (score 2):

I concentrate one the bold line: *Leichtes Blut* is a phrase rarely used today, a tiny bit more frequent is *leichtblütig*, which can be found in a [dictionary](https://www.dwds.de/wb/leichtbl%C3%BCtig) and which I would translate as **jolly**.

*Heißes Blut* ist much more frequent and means that emotions or passions overwhelm the subject. So I would translate to:

> to think of the song (?), if jolliness turns to passion/emotion.

Answer (score 2):

As @Roland said in his comment, this is perhaps a typo and should read "Leid" (sorrow, suffering, hardship) instead of "Lied" (song).

"Leichtes Blut" or in adjectivic form "leichtblütig" is idiomatic and means not being concerned with future or what it might bring, as @Guidot mentioned in his answer.

"Heißes Blut" (or, in the same adjectivic way, "heißblütig") is similarly idiomatic and means *full of temperament* or *agitated* (depending on context also with the negative connotation of being short-tempered).

> Auch in heitern Sonnentagen tät es manchem Menschen gut,
> Etwa an das *Leid* zu denken, wenn zu heiß das leichte Blut,

This would make about the following suggestion: even in times of good fortune one would do good to make himself aware of possible (coming) hardship in order to not get too big for his britches.

The following attempt at translation lacks any poetic value but tries to preserve the meaning of the original:

> Our live is like the journey of a wanderer at night,
> Who hasn't thought in dire times about these words.
> And even on days full of sunshine some would do better
> to think about sorrow, if tempers are getting too hot

> Joys [celebrations] are necessary, lest one wants to shrivel
> but wisdom tells us: not too often, not too much!
> Who is able to put his life into order even in joyous summertimes
> will be better prepared for the darkness of winter.

Notice that "Freudenbecher" is meaning the cups one drinks during joyous celebrations. I replaced that with "joy" (alternatively "celebrations" because i am not sure if "beakers of joy", as @planetmaker suggests in his comment brings across this meaning. If it does, I suggest you use that instead of my translation.

Answer (score 2):

I will try a translation (and I will assume as by Roland's comment that the original uses 'Leid' instead of 'Lied'):

> Trinkspruch
>
> Unser Leben gleicht der Reise eines Wandrers in der Nacht.
> Wer hat nicht in trüber Stunde diese Worte schon bedacht?
> Auch in heitern Sonnentagen tät es manchem Menschen gut,
> Etwa an das Leid zu denken, wenn zu heiß das leichte Blut,
>
> Freudenbecher sind zwar nötig, wenn man nicht verkümmern will.
> Doch es ruft uns zu die Klugheit: Nicht zu oft und nicht zuviel!
> Wer sein Leben weiß zu regeln auch in froher Sommerszeit,
> Ist viel besser vorbereitet für des Winters Dunkelheit.

Literal:

> Toast
>
> Our life is like a wanderer's journey through the night
> Who didn't ponder these words in a gloomy hour?
> Also on sunny days some people would do well
> to remember the sorrow when optimism runs high
>
> Beakers of joy are essential if you don't want to wither.
> But wisdom calls to us: not to often, not too much!
> Who knows to manage their life in happy summertime,
> is prepared better for the darkness of winter.

Maybe more poetic, at least trying to find a rhyme:

> Toast
>
> Life is like a wanderer's journey through the night.
> Who didn't ponder this in gloomy hour?
> Some people would do well on days sunny and bright
> Even then remember the sorrow, that things can turn sour.
>
> Essential are beakers of joy, so you don't wither,
> "Not too often, not too much!" is wisdom's call.
> Such those, who do well in jolly summer time till fall,
> are hardened better for the winter's dark and shiver.

(yes, "Reim dich oder ich fress dich!" ;) )

Comment: Well done. You might consider "are hardened better" instead of "are prepared much better" in the last line, IMHO it fills the rhythm better. Also, "Essential are beakers of joy" seems to rhythmically fit better.

Comment: @bakunin thanks, good suggestions. I take them :)

Comment: I  like the rhyme as well!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Our life is like the journey 
>  of a wan-der-er at night
> Who has not have had this thought 
>  when the time was not as bright

> On these joyous days of summer 
> it would treat some people well 
> if they'd too remember sorrow
>  / if that song is well remembered 
> when in cheerfulness they dwell

> Pints of joy are necessary
> to prevent the soul from crush
> But wisdom keeps reminding us
> not to often, not to much

> Those who know themselves to handle
> when summer shows it's merry mark
> Are well prepared for whats to come
> when in Winter 'ts getting dark

More of a free translation that tries to keep up the rhyme scheme.

Edit: if anybody knows how to format that well, please suggest an edit :)